# When to start animations during Activity lifecycles?

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, android-view, android-lifecycle

It's odd but I've never seen something well documented as to how we can perform animations at the right time so that they can be seen smoothly while the Activity's life cycle is progressing.

If for example you start an animation `onCreate` then you won't even see it happen.

Also if Activity A starts Activity B with `startActivityForResult` and you want to start an animation `onActivityResult` (to show user's selection) then once again you don't see anything because the transition from Activity B to Activity A takes some time.

How can we know when to start the animation in these cases? I'm more interested in the `onActivityResult` case right now.

Also how can we know in general if a view can REALLY perform an animation that the user will actually see?

Comment: There is another callback:  [onEnterAnimationComplete()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onEnterAnimationComplete()). Does this work with your animations?

Comment: I tried that too and it is indeed the best timing to start an animation...The bad thing is that on some Sumsung devices I've tested it never gets called (Thank you once again Samsung). Also the onResume case would remain unsolved

Comment: If it's not guaranteed to be called then it's not really useful :(

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `onResume`.

[Quote from Android docs:](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume())

> Called after onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle), onRestart(), or onPause(), for your activity to start interacting with the user. This is a good place to begin animations, open exclusive-access devices (such as the camera), etc.

In the same docs you also find a way on how to check if the activity is displayed:

> Keep in mind that onResume is not the best indicator that your activity is visible to the user; a system window such as the keyguard may be in front. Use onWindowFocusChanged(boolean) to know for certain that your activity is visible to the user (for example, to resume a game).

Comment: As you pointed out your self onResume is not a good bet...I tried onWindowFocusChanged as well and same thing happened. I missed the first steps of the animation.

Comment: No, `onResume` is the best place to start an animation. It just doesn't guarantee that if on resume is called, the activity is fully visible. If the things are still not working, maybe you can share with use what you want to achieve and what is not working, because we can't really see what's happening in your animation

Answer (score 0):

For a standard flow `onResume()` may be considered as a good point to fire an animation. But if you have some other use cases, then you can initiate to delay animation start to the next frame, where everything is (hopefully) setup already.

That can be done via `Handler` class.

```
    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // start animation
        }
    });
```

Using this technique you can delay your animations start from both `onCreate()` and `onActivityResult()`.

Comment: onResume is called at about the same time that the Activity transition animations starts. So starting an animaton there is not working (as I've tested ) because the Activity transition is still happening. The animation misses it's first steps. Of course I can set a startOffset but that's not an elegant solution.

Comment: If you have a activity transition, then you can set a click listener, and as soon as transition ends - only then start your animation. `getWindow().getExitTransition().addListener(... onTransitionEnd() {...})`

Comment: I m aware of that but this is available from API 21 and above. Right now about 25% of Android users are below 21. So this is not a viable solution

Comment: By saying "activity transition" did you mean a shared element transition? If no, then running in `onResume()` should be ok. If you still do not achieve your requirement, why won't you use `Handler.post()` approach?

Comment: Because setting an arbitrary delay is not an elegant solution. different phones have different default transitions with different tranistion durations. The point of the question is to find the right way to do it...

Comment: @Anonymous, there is no `arbitrary delay` in my answer.

Comment: I assumed that's what you meant because I tried it using just a plain Handler without delay and nothing changed.